# How can I stop joins from adding rows in my match query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, functional-programming

I'm having difficulty translating what I want into functional programming, since I think imperatively. Basically, I have a table of forms, and a table of expectations. In the Expectation view, I want it to look through the forms table and tell me if each one found a match. However, when I try to use joins to accomplish this, the joins are adding rows to the Expectation table when two or more forms match. I do not want this.

In an imperative fashion, I want the equivalent of this:

```
ForEach (row in Expectation table)
{
    if (any form in the Form table matches the criteria)
    {
         MatchID = form.ID;
         SignDate = form.SignDate;
         ...
    }
}
```

What I have in SQL is this:

```
SELECT
    e.*, match.ID, match.SignDate, ...
FROM
   POFDExpectation e LEFT OUTER JOIN
   (SELECT MIN(ID) as MatchID, MIN(SignDate) as MatchSignDate, 
        COUNT(*) as MatchCount, ...
    FROM Form f
    GROUP BY (matching criteria columns)
        ) match
        ON (form.[match criteria] = expectation.[match criteria])
```

Which works okay, but very slowly, and every time there are TWO matches, a row is added to the Expectation results. Mathematically I understand that a join is a cross multiply and this is expected, but I'm unsure how to do this without them. Subquery perhaps?

I'm not able to give too many further details about the implementation, but I'll be happy to try any suggestion and respond with the results. I have 880 Expectation rows, and 942 results being returned. If I only allow results that match one form, I get 831 results. Neither are desirable, so if yours gets me to exactly 880, yours is the accepted answer.

Edit: I am using SQL Server 2008 R2, though a generic solution would be best.

Sample code:

```
--DROP VIEW ExpectationView; DROP TABLE Forms; DROP TABLE Expectations;
--Create Tables and View
CREATE TABLE Forms (ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, ReportYear int, Name varchar(100), Complete bit, SignDate datetime)
GO
CREATE TABLE Expectations (ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, ReportYear int, Name varchar(100))
GO
CREATE VIEW ExpectationView AS select e.*, filed.MatchID, filed.SignDate, ISNULL(filed.FiledCount, 0) as FiledCount, ISNULL(name.NameCount, 0) as NameCount from Expectations e LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(select MIN(ID) as MatchID, ReportYear, Name, Complete, Min(SignDate) as SignDate, COUNT(*) as FiledCount from Forms f GROUP BY ReportYear, Name, Complete) filed
on filed.ReportYear = e.ReportYear AND filed.Name like '%'+e.Name+'%' AND filed.Complete = 1 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(select MIN(ID) as MatchID, ReportYear, Name, COUNT(*) as NameCount from Forms f GROUP BY ReportYear, Name) name 
on name.ReportYear = e.ReportYear AND name.Name like '%'+e.Name+'%'
GO
--Insert Text Data
INSERT INTO Forms (ReportYear, Name, Complete, SignDate)
SELECT 2011, 'Bob Smith', 1, '2012-03-01' UNION ALL
SELECT 2011, 'Bob Jones', 1, '2012-10-04' UNION ALL
SELECT 2011, 'Bob', 1, '2012-07-20'
GO
INSERT INTO Expectations (ReportYear, Name)
SELECT 2011, 'Bob'
GO
SELECT * FROM ExpectationView --Should only return 1 result, returns 9
```

The 'filed' shows that they have completed a form, 'name' shows that they may have started one but not finished it. My view has four different 'match criteria' - each a little more strict, and counts each. 'Name Only Matches', 'Loose Matches', 'Matches' (default), 'Tight Matches' (used if there are more than one default match.

Comment: Can you show your table structure, sample data, rows that you don't want returned (or show us which rows you want returned exactly), and fill in the blanks for the above query? Or at least enough details to reproduce the case where you get extra rows? We can't magically tell you which 62 rows don't belong, but if we know the source data and where you end up we might be able to formulate a better query. Also, PLEASE indicate the version of SQL Server you are using. This information is very useful and does not need to be a secret.

Comment: SAMPLE DATA is always the key.

Comment: I am working on writing some up, however, (perhaps in another question) I want to know how to write the equivalent of a foreach in SQL - "loop over this dataset, and add x to each row". Joins (or perhaps the ones I've been doing) are not this.

Comment: @Ehryk there are almost *ALWAYS* better solutions than doing the equivalent of foreach. While this is a logical approach in OO programming, this is exactly the opposite of what SQL is good at. If you want to do a foreach, you may as well just pull all the data back to your application and do the loop there. If you share with us more details we can show you how to write a MUCH more efficient set-based approach to solving the same problem. Whenever you think of solving a SQL query using a loop you are thinking about the problem the wrong way. Not your fault per se, just reality.

Comment: I understand that completely, but in this case it's too inefficient to draw it into my application and do the logic there. Could you point me to some broad examples of loops / foreach 'translated' into SQL? This isn't the only case I've thought of this. In one instance, I built a temp table, set a counter at the ID start, and incremented though. I know it's 'bad', but where's a list of 'here's how to do it in SQL' (generically)?

Comment: http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql/thinking-in-sets-129772 http://sqlserverconsulting.blogspot.com/2009/12/thinking-in-sets.html http://www.real-sql-guy.com/2012/02/20-abuses-procedurally-going-in-circles.html

Comment: SQL is not designed to do a foreach, that's the antithesis of relational mathematics. Do not try to do a procedural command in a non-procedural language. That's the worst idea.

Comment: Wait a moment, how is 1000 rows "too inefficient"?

Comment: This is suspect `(SELECT MIN(ID) as MatchID, MIN(SignDate) as MatchSignDate,` The SignDate could be `{ January, February, March }` for each ID, but it should not have duplicate themselves `{ January, January, March }`. That will really return two rows when you subsequently joined them to the outer query

Comment: Because the application server and database server are hosted on different machines, I'd rather not pull two tables out and match them all, and I certainly can't pull them all out and run a query for each one. It's 1000 rows now, but it will grow.

Comment: How can the query match only one row to join if there are multiple SignDate matched? Please select a more unique column for MIN, perhaps if there are none, you should generate one yourself, any dummy unique column would perfectly fit MIN

Comment: That seems to be selecting the earliest SignDate properly when there are duplicate matches. I'm missing your point on the multiple IDs comment, there WILL be multiple ones, I want the lowest ID (form started first) and the earliest SignDate.

Comment: The earliest SignDate could be duplicate themselves. This is what I meant for using a unique column http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35a5e/1 instead of non-unique column(date has duplicate themselves) http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35a5e/2   The first test MIN(autonumber) correctly pick-up one row only, unlike the latter MIN(Date) picks two January.  If you really can't introduce a new column, pick a column which you think has no duplicates among themselves. The earliest date on sqlfiddle is January, which is duplicate themselves

Comment: Can you *please* also show the exact values in the row you expected?

Comment: Better yet, reproduce the error here at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ And stackoverflow gurus can hunt down the causes of your error and give you an answer consequently. The rows sampling need not be that big, just a few rows that could illustrate your problem

Comment: Use sqlfiddle's Text to DDL, so you don't have to handcraft the DDL

Comment: At this point, it's not important to me WHICH values are in the row. I'd prefer the Min(ID) and Min(SignDate) that I wrote. The key is, I want ONE row returned. I have ONE expectation, and it's returning 9 rows! Under no condition (no matter what is duplicated, etc.) I NEVER want rows added to the Expectation list.

Comment: Does this link work for you? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7ca27/1            My goal is 1 row, not 9.

Comment: @Aaron: From the context of his statements, I believe that Ehryk is looking for **foreach**'s functional equivalent (i.e., SELECT..FROM), rather than it's syntactical/procedural equivalent (WHILE/Cursors).

Comment: @RBarryYoung - you are correct, but I'm curious now: can I make true loops in SQL with WHILE/Cursors? How is this done?

Comment: You can, but you should ***not***.  (Which was Aaron's point also).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I do it when I want to keep to a JOIN-type query format:

```
SELECT
    e.*, 
    match.ID, 
    match.SignDate, 
    ...
FROM        POFDExpectation e 
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT  TOP 1
        MIN(ID) as MatchID, 
        MIN(SignDate) as MatchSignDate, 
        COUNT(*) as MatchCount, 
        ...
    FROM    Form f
    WHERE   form.[match criteria] = expectation.[match criteria] 
    GROUP BY ID (matching criteria columns)   
    -- Add ORDER BY here to control which row is TOP 1
    ) match
```

It usually performs better as well.

---

Semantically, {CROSS|OUTER} APPLY (table-expression)  specifies a table-expression that is called once for each row in the preceding table expressions of the FROM clause and then joined to them.  Pragmatically, however, the compiler treats it almost identically to a JOIN.

The practical difference is that unlike a JOIN table-expression, the APPLY table-expression is dynamically re-evaluated for each row.  So instead of an ON clause, it relies on its own logic and WHERE clauses to limit/match its rows to the preceding table-expressions.  This also allows it to make reference to the column-values of the preceding table-expressions, ***inside*** its own internal subquery expression.  (This is not possible in a JOIN)

The reason that we want this here, instead of a JOIN, is that we need a TOP 1 in the sub-query to limit its returned rows, however, that means that we need to move the ON clause conditions to the internal WHERE clause so that it will get applied ***before*** the TOP 1 is evaluated.  And *that* means that we need an APPLY here, instead of the more usual JOIN.

Comment: Could you summarize what 'APPLY' is/does? I'll look it up in more detail later, but a quick SQL idiot's interpretation would be helpful.

Comment: Is APPLY not a rather decent analogue to ForEach then? It's certainly much more like it than JOIN.

Comment: OUTER APPLY walkthrough http://www.ienablemuch.com/2012/04/outer-apply-walkthrough.html  OUTER APPLY IS called LATERAL in other database, it means execution of the query can only be determined upon later querying of the source row.  The difference with JOIN, JOIN perform the operation independently of the outer tables or queries, then yield a set out of it, and then you can pass that set to another JOIN.  JOIN is more like batch processing, many things can be done earlier independently of other tables/queries. OUTER APPLY is more like interactive, i.e. it is triggered by each row

Comment: In terms of JOINs. OUTER APPLY is the spitting image of LEFT JOIN, CROSS APPLY is the counterpart of INNER JOIN

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you do it when you DON'T want to keep a JOIN-type query format? Sub-selects? What are my options here?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Is there any way to NOT group them? As in, give me the first one that satisfies the conditions in the where clauses, along with the count, without grouping?

Comment: Busy working today, but I'll take time to answer all of these in the body of my post later on ...

Comment: So you want a PICK_ANY_ROW() function?

Comment: I asked this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444333/sql-server-how-can-i-use-the-count-clause-without-grouping/10444613) and got the answer: `SELECT TOP 1 ID, <other columns>, COUNT(*) as MatchCount OVER () FROM ...` and that got me what I wanted (no aggregate functions on each column, just the top 1 row plus how many items matched).

Answer (score 1):

@RBarryYoung answered the question as I asked it, but there was a second question that I didn't make very clear. What I really wanted was a combination of his answer and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444333/sql-server-how-can-i-use-the-count-clause-without-grouping/10444613), so for the record here's what I used:

```
SELECT
    e.*, 
     ...
    match.ID, 
    match.SignDate, 
    match.MatchCount
FROM 
    POFDExpectation e 
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT  TOP 1
            ID as MatchID, 
            ReportYear,
             ...
            SignDate as MatchSignDate, 
            COUNT(*) as MatchCount OVER ()
        FROM
            Form f
        WHERE
            form.[match criteria] = expectation.[match criteria]
        -- Add ORDER BY here to control which row is TOP 1
        ) match
```